# Django login page with parameters

Tags: python, django

In Django application I am working on right now, user session is marked as multiple after same user login on another device, so after page reloading first user logs out and is redirected to `admin/login` page.

Need to show first user warning about this on `admin/login` page. The only thing, that came up on my mind for now is to add `GET` parameter to this page url, check it in view, and show this warning. But I can't find the class/method to override, where I can check if session is expired or not and add `GET` parameter, say `multiple_sessions=1` url.

I assume, it would look something like this:

```
def logout(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.session['multiple']:
        super(CustomLogout, self).logout(request, redirect_to='/admin/login?multiple_session=1', *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        super(CustomLogout, self).logout(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

So the question is, what exactly method is responsible for redirecting user to `logout`?

Any other ideas of achieving this behaviour are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean the `SessionMiddleware`?

Comment: I used custom middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this custom middleware class to achieve needed behavior:

```
class LogoutMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if hasattr(request, 'user'):
            if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.session.exists(request.session.session_key):
                current_session = Session.objects.get(pk=request.session.session_key)
                if current_session.old == True:
                    response_redirect = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('logout'))
                    response_redirect.set_cookie('multiple-sessions', True)
                    return response_redirect 
        return response
```

Then, if the login view finds this cookie, it renders warning in template.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood correctly. Your question is, how to show a message to the user after they logged out, is that correct?

Django has the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/) to do just that, showing messages to a user.

```
from django.contrib import messages

def logout(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.session['multiple']:
        messages.info(request, 'Something multiple sessions.')
    super(CustomLogout, self).logout(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Not exactly, what I was asking about, but useful, thanks!